# Displaying a human readable date time in angular js that comes from rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, datetime-format

I want to show human readable date time in my frontend. My data comes from rails backend. When I use `{{ item.created_at }}` it shows the time like rails way 2016-10-10T10:29:47.993Z. But How can I show this like 5 days ago, 3 hours ago in angular js?

Answer (score 2):

To format dates in angular you can use `date` [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) like this:

```
{{ item.created_at | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' }}
```

You are looking for a very particular format so I think you need to build a **custom filter** to show exactly that. You can use this filter scaffolding:

```
.filter('customDate', function() {

  return function(date) {
    // 1. Get current date
    // 2. Get diff from expression date to current
    // 3. Apply your format and return result; 
  };

});
```

Lastly there is a library called [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to manipulate dates and times and there is an [angular version](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) of that:

Check the [am-time-ago](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#am-time-ago-directive) directive of the library:

```
<span am-time-ago="item.created_at"></span>
```

Comment: {{ item.created_at | data:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' }} is not working. May be item.created_at should be converted to mili seconds. this is the format rails gives us 2016-10-10T10:29:47.993Z.

Comment: @SalmanMahmud Sorry, I had a typo is `date`  instead of  `data`. Try it again please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Create a filter for that, for reusability of code

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.date = "1992-05-07T22:00:00.000Z";
});

jimApp.filter('dateFilter', function() {
     function calculateDate(date) {
         date = new Date(date);
         var year = date.getFullYear();
         var month = date.getMonth()+1;
         var day = date.getDate();
         return day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
     }

     return function(date) { 
           return calculateDate(date);
     }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div>{{date | dateFilter}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can achieve this using default behavior of angular date filter.